# AJAX - set object property in side $.post with 'self' reference not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, properties

this is driving me crazy.

It cannot seem to set the value of property from inside AJAX.

Below is my code

```
function Captcha(userKey) {
    var self = this;

    this.key;
    this.getCaptchaKey = function(userKey) {
        $.post('/api/captcha/get-key',data, function(data, status,jqXHR) {
            if(status) {
                self.key = data.data.captchaKey;

            }
        },"json");
    };
    this.getCaptchaKey(userKey);
}
```

I set 'this' as 'self' to reference from inside AJAX call.

then when I console.log()  this object itself outside the object, it tells me the value is already set.

```
self.captcha = new Captcha(self.userKey);
    self.captchaKey = self.captcha.key

    console.log(self.captcha);
```

so 'self.captcha' return the object with correct value of 'key' set from AJAX call.

but when I console.log(self.captcha.key), it says 'undefined'

I have been googling everywhere but couldn't find answer.

Comment: What is self in the second block? In my opinion self is a bad variable name since self has a meaning. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.self

Comment: just like epascarello says, u need to handle it asyncronousely with a callback. i.e. function Captcha(userKey, callback) {... if(status) {
                callback(data.data.captchaKey);
            } and then do new Captcha(self.userKey, function (key) {self.captchaKey = key});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is the fact you are treating an asynchronous call as synchronous. You are reading the value before the Ajax call returns.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but I don't call for the object right after the object is created. Even when I call it on click event ( which gives it enough time to get data Asynchronously )   And when I  return the object, it has the property with the right value.   I can't get that value =(    Any other advice please?

Comment: Thanks Epascarello, you got it right. I was assigning the value too early to a variable and using that variable, which makes it undefined.   Thank you very much!